# Taking shortest path

Tags: c, data-structures, dijkstra, bellman-ford

Hey I am trying to code in C for the least energy needed to move from one city to another. So far I have been able to read content from a file. I am not sure what I should do now. The code and text file is as following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct value {
  int num;
  char start_vertex[250];
  char destination_vertex[250];
} value;

int main()
{
  const int nLines = 43; // number of lines in my text file
  FILE * fptr;
  value * valuesPtr = malloc(sizeof(value) * nLines);

  if (!valuesPtr) {
    puts("cannot allocate memory");
    return -1;
  }

  if((fptr = fopen("energy.txt", "r")) == NULL)
  {
    perror("Error opening file");
    return -1;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < nLines; i++ )
  {
      if (fscanf(fptr, "%249s %249s %d",
                 valuesPtr[i].start_vertex,
                 valuesPtr[i].destination_vertex,
                 &valuesPtr[i].num) != 3) {
        printf("errored file line %d\n", i);
        break;
      }

      printf("\nStart vertex: %s \nDestination vertex: %s \nWeight: %d\n\n",
             valuesPtr[i].start_vertex, valuesPtr[i].destination_vertex, valuesPtr[i].num);
  }
  free(valuesPtr);
  fclose(fptr);

  return 0;
}
```

This code only prints out the starting and the destination city and the energy needed to go from one to the other. 
I have been looking in to using Bellman- Ford or Dijkstra algorithm but I am not sure how to implement them in to my code
This is the energy file:

```
York    Hull    60
Leeds   Doncaster   -47
Liverpool   Nottingham  161
Manchester  Sheffield   61
Reading Oxford  -43
Oxford  Birmingham  103
Birmingham  Leicester   63
Liverpool   Blackpool   79
Carlisle    Newcastle   92
Nottingham  Birmingham  77
Leeds   York    39
Glasgow Edinburgh   74
Moffat  Carlisle    65
Doncaster   Hull    76
Northampton Birmingham  90
Leicester   Lincoln 82
Sheffield   Birmingham  122
Lincoln Doncaster   63
Sheffield   Doncaster   29
Bristol Reading 130
Hull    Nottingham  145
Blackpool   Leeds   116
Birmingham  Bristol 139
Manchester  Leeds   64
Carlisle    Blackpool   140
Leicester   Northampton -61
Newcastle   York    135
Glasgow Moffat  -28
Leicester   Sheffield   100
Carlisle    Liverpool   -30
Birmingham  Manchester  129
Oxford  Bristol 116
Leeds   Hull    89
Edinburgh   Carlisle    154
Nottingham  Sheffield   61
Liverpool   Manchester  56
Carlisle    Glasgow 50
Sheffield   Lincoln 74
York    Doncaster   55
Newcastle   Edinburgh   177
Leeds   Sheffield   53
Northampton Oxford  68
Manchester  Carlisle    20
```

Can someone give me a structured plan to what I need to do in order to make my algorithm. I want to see the least energy required and the cities you will have to go through in order to go from Leicester to Moffat, Hull to Oxford, and Lincoln to Bristol.

Comment: I think the first step should be to transform the raw input into a suitable graph representation, for example a matrix. (That involves assigning an index to each of the cities by creating a look-up table or a dectionary. If you only have to solve this particular problem, you could hard-code the data into your program, which might be easier.)

Comment: How do I go about doing it? I was looking in to adjacency matrix, but I am not sure how to implement it to my code. If you could show me a way of doing it. It would be much appreciated. If you want, you can modify my current code :)

Comment: Just do the quick and easy thing: Create an enum of all city names, then hard-code the energies into yor code. [Here's how](https://ideone.com/iJdXXt). You should now be good to unleash your Bellman-Ford powers onto the data.

Comment: Hey I just saw the code, I do not understand it. Is it possible if you could explain it to me please

Comment: It's just a way to get the data into the program without fiddling with an external input file. The `enum` creates values for Birmingham (0) to York (20). The rest doesn't really need explanation.

Comment: Ahh about that, is it possible if you could tell me how I can do it with the file. I am learning how to use data from a file and hopefully save the answer into a different file later on, but I haven't gone to that part yet

Comment: So can someone help me out with it please

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
```

class GFG {

```
static int V = 9; 
int minDistance(int[] dist, 
                bool[] sptSet) 
{ 
    int min = int.MaxValue, min_index = -1; 

    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++) 
        if (sptSet[v] == false && dist[v] <= min) { 
            min = dist[v]; 
            min_index = v; 
        } 

    return min_index; 
} 

void printSolution(int[] dist, int n) 
{ 
    Console.Write("Vertex     Distance "
                  + "from Source\n"); 
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) 
        Console.Write(i + " \t\t " + dist[i] + "\n"); 
} 

void dijkstra(int[, ] graph, int src) 
{ 
    int[] dist = new int[V]; // The output array. dist[i] 

    bool[] sptSet = new bool[V]; 


    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) { 
        dist[i] = int.MaxValue; 
        sptSet[i] = false; 
    } 


    dist[src] = 0; 

    for (int count = 0; count < V - 1; count++) { 
        int u = minDistance(dist, sptSet); 

        sptSet[u] = true; 

        for (int v = 0; v < V; v++) 


            if (!sptSet[v] && graph[u, v] != 0 &&  
                 dist[u] != int.MaxValue && dist[u] + graph[u, v] < dist[v]) 
                dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u, v]; 
    } 

            printSolution(dist, V); 
} 


public static void Main() 
{ 

    int[, ] graph = new int[, ] { { 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0 }, 
                                  { 4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0 }, 
                                  { 0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2 }, 
                                  { 0, 0, 7, 0, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                                  { 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                                  { 0, 0, 4, 14, 10, 0, 2, 0, 0 }, 
                                  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 6 }, 
                                  { 8, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7 }, 
                                  { 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0 } }; 
    GFG t = new GFG(); 
    t.dijkstra(graph, 0); 
}
```

}

Comment: Hey I am not sure how to implement it in to my code

Comment: (1) Your answer is only code. Please explain what it does and why you think it answers the question. (2) That's not C. (3) The Dijkstra algorithm cannot handle negative edge weights, but the problem has them.

Comment: Yeah the best way to go about it is Bellman Ford algorithm,  but there might be negative cycles in the code. There are 21 cities in total and there are 43 journeys